# How old does one need to be in order to mine or use Bitcoins?

Tags: legal

How old does one need to be in order to mine or use Bitcoins? Do I need to be 18 years old, or just 13? Is it illegal if a child uses Bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can use Bitcoins there is no age specification. It's good that you start with crypto currencies at early age so that you can make a handful of money while you turn 18 but don't get do indulge into cryptos so that you put all other things aside.